# The cardinality of Lebesgue sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A=\{S\;|\;S \subset \mathbb R^n, S\text{ is Lebesgue measurable}\}$. What is the cardinality of $A$? Is it the same as the cardinality of all of the real numbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $A$ is the standard Cantor set, then $A\subseteq\mathbb R^1$ is Lebesgue measurable, and has measure zero and the same size as the reals. Any subset of $A$ is also measurable, so there are as many Lebesgue measurable subsets as there are sets of reals (which is strictly larger than the size of the reals).

The same holds in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>1$, since $[0,1]\times\{0\}^{n-1}$ is Lebesgue measurable of measure $0$ and has the same size as $\mathbb R$.

The key here is that Lebesgue measure is *complete*, so any subset of a measure zero set is measurable. In contrast, there are only as many Borel sets as there are real numbers.

Comment: Hence $|A| = 2^c$.

Comment: Thank you! I just know why. And I found a mistake in my book, which caused me to ask this 'simple' question.

Comment: In my book, A's cardinality is 2^aleph0, which is actually wrong.

Comment: That's an unfortunate typo! (From personal experience, removing all typos from what I write is impossible, no matter how careful I attempt to be.)

Comment: @Andres, one can always write a Miller-esque warning about typos; and then in the next edition blame all typos on those who found the previous ones! :-)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo What? If A is the standard Cantor set (as the answer states), then its cardinality should be the same as that of the continuum, which is 2^aleph0 and not 2^c. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Trixie Any subset of the Cantor set is measurable, and I am counting the size of the collection of all such sets, not the size of any of them in particular.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo But you see my confusion when A was defined to be the Cantor set. |A| should be 2^aleph0 just as Phil Wang's book indicates, no? Then why are you are both saying the book is in error?

Comment: @Trixie $A$ denotes the Cantor set in my post. $A$ denotes something else in the body of the question.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**

Note that the Cantor set, or some copy of it in $\Bbb R^n$ is Lebesgue measurable with measure zero.

1. **Every** subset of a null set is measurable.
2. The cardinality of the Cantor set is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I understand! Thank you!